# Do not allow windows applications to take control of the master volume keys?

Tags: windows-7, audio, keyboard

I have a volume wheel on my keyboard which I LOVE, however it annoys me when certain applications such as the youtube player and some videogames take control of the keyboard volume input and don't let me change the volume!!

I'm running Windows 7. Is there a way to disallow all applications from taking control of the volume keys on the keyboard? ...leaving it up to Windows to do its own damn business? Or maybe some sort of passthrough program that runs at all times listening for the volume keys and feeding them to Windows?

Thanks for any suggestions.